# Is it possible to run into a race condition with a service declared as static in Android?

Tags: android, service, synchronization

I've the following structure for the launching of certain services in Android:

I've an initial service that checks that certain conditions needed to launch some services are met, if they happen the services start.

When those services are going to perform their key actions it's checked if those conditions still apply, if they don't they stop themselves, along with all other services that may get a wrong result because of that condition. Then they call that initial service that will keep on checking about these conditions, once they are met it will finish itself and start the services once again.

It's not useful to keep that initial service running permanently, as some of the conditions are not related to any android event so the only way is to check them in an infinite loop that will break when that conditions are met, which is pretty battery consuming.

It might be possible that two services get to try to create that same initial service at the same time.

I mean it might be possible a situation like this:

Service 1:

Finds this code to init service:

```
public static Intent myinitialService=null;

[...]

if (StaticMethods.myinitialService==null)
                {
                    StaticMethods.myinitialService= new Intent(getBaseContext(),myinitialService.class);
                    startService(StaticMethods.myinitialService);

                }
```

At the same time there's a service2 that gets to read at the same time the "if (StaticMethods.myinitialService==null)", causing either service1 and service2 to start the same initial service, which might also end up creating more than 1 service of each, and so on.

But I think that just by declaring the variable as static would make this impossible to happen, even if some situation like this were to happen only one of the services would start, but I'd like to be sure and if it weren't the case what could be done in order to avoid that situation.

Comment: Actually, the service is created only once (if stopSelf or stopService are not called). Consequent startService() calls don't create a service but send a onStartCommand event to it.

Comment: @user1055395, thanks for your answer, but it doesn't help with my problem, even if doesn't start a new one, it could also end up executing code it doesn't have to.